# Trouble with basic callback blocks in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

brand new to Swift here. Trying to figure out how to do a very simple call back block from any asynchronous function I write.

For example:

```
 func downloadData(completion: (success: Bool) -> Void){

        let success: Bool
        //Some asynchronous task here
        success = true
        //Asynchronous task finished
        //Now I want to pass this back
        completion(success)

    }
```

I want to be able to call this function and get the value of the success variable in the block. However I'm getting an error "Missing argument label success in call". Don't understand what is going on here. Why would I need to include the argument label? Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `completion(success: success)`

Comment: So this is just a swift thing then? The label must be included too? Objective-C the label isn't included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the choice:

Either you add the label in the call

```
completion(success: success)
```

or you omit the label in the declaration

```
func downloadData(completion: (Bool) -> Void){
```

The rule is: *all declared labels must be passed*.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for that

Comment: If you want to include the label for self-documentation, but don't want callers to have to use it, you can break the "rule" as follows: `func downloadData( completion:(_ success: Bool) -> Void)`. See [External Parameter Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166)

Comment: That doesn't affect closures as completion blocks.